# What DPI should I be creating images at for use in an Android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know there's a big difference between the `drawable-*` folders, but what should I do to create my images? What DPI should I use? As it's been said, you can always go down (in DPI) but you can't go up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you create your original artwork in the highest resolution you need (or even higher, just in case :). This means you should target high dpi, which is set to 240dpi on ANdroid.

Comment: I agree with this but watch out in photoshop (and probably other photo editors) because there doesn't seem to be a "DPI" setting. Under "Resolution" there only seems to be pixels per inch or per cm. So you'll need to calculate that.